# ImageView image load logic from gallery

Tags: objective-c, image

I am having 2 ImageView. I want to load image from gallery into ImageView. My requirement is, if I select the image 1st time, then image should be loaded into ImageView 1, and when I select image 2nd time, image should be loaded into ImageView 2.

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo :(NSDictionary *)info
        {
          int  count=0;

            iscamera=YES;
            _imageuser.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            _imageuser1.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            _imageuser2.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            if (ipc.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum) {
                if (count==0) {
                    pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageuser.image);
                    pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageuser1.image);
                }

        else if (count== 1)
        {
            pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageuser.image);
            pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageuser2.image);
        }
                count ++;
            }

            else{
                pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self rotateUIImage:_imageuser.image clockwise:YES]);

            }
            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

Comment: Are u asking about the same image selection from gallery for both times.

Comment: i am asking if when i click on buton and select image from gallery then image should be loaded in imgview1 and if i select again image by cliclking on button image should be uploaded in imageview2. i am having 1 uibutton and 2 imageview.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //initialize count with 0
let count = 0
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    // get image
  let capturedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    // you can set image to any imageview according to count value
   if(count == 0){
        firstImageView.image = capturedImage

    }else if (count == 1){

        secondImageView.image = capturedImage
    }else{


    }
    // increment count so that we can set image to appropriate image view
    count ++
}
```

Comment: i am doing like dis actully i m doing dis in objective c

Comment: -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo :(NSDictionary *)info
{ int  count=0;
    iscamera=YES;
  _imageuser1.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    _imageuser2.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     if (ipc.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum) {
        if (count==0) {  pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageuser1.image);
        }
       else if (count== 1)
{ pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageuser2.image);
}
        count ++;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can check the NSdata of the image in image1.
If it exists supply the 2nd selected  image to second imageView otherwise supply it to first imageView.